# How to group the results of a query to avoid repeated lines with same information?

Tags: sql

This is a newbie question, but maybe someone could answer me. I have  a table as below:

TableA:

| Shipment | Status | EnteredDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 31-12-2022 |
| 1 | 55 | 31-11-2022 |
| 1 | 55 | 29-10-2022 |

TableB:

| Shipment | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MDM |

My desired result would be:

| Shipment | Source | Last Entered Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MDM | 31-12-2022 |

Right now I am using

```
SELECT 
TableA.SHIPMENT,
FIRST_VALUE(CAST(TableA.ENTEREDDATE AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY TableA.Shipment ORDER BY TableA.ENTEREDDATE DESC) AS "Last Entered Date".

FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.Shipment  = TableA.Shipment

GROUP BY TableA.Shipment
,TableA.EnteredDate
```

But unfortunately I am getting three rows instead of only one.

| Shipment | Source | Last Entered Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MDM | 31-12-2022 |
| 1 | MDM | 31-12-2022 |
| 1 | MDM | 31-12-2022 |

How can I solve it?

Edit ** I just wrote the table with 1 shipment but I have several shipments on it.

Comment: Use ```SELECT DISTINCT ...``` to get only one row

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: No need for a window function, just use `MAX(EnteredDate)`.

Comment: When someone gives you the answer that you were looking for, remember to mark that answer as "Accepted"

Answer (score 0):

You did not tag your database. Below would work with almost any database:

```
select TableB.Shipment, TableB.Source, lastShipment.lastDate as LastEnteredDate
from TableB 
inner join 
(select Shipment, max(EnteredDate) as lastDate
from TableA
group by Shipment
) lastShipment on TableB.Shipment = lastShipment.Shipment;
```

Comment: Using sub-query is not efficient, try to avoid using them

Comment: @ElNicho, at least it works. Then I can write an optimized version. You cannot do a generalization saying subqueries are not efficient without knowing the database. There is a reason to use subquery (here it was MAX() and may not be needed).

Comment: *at least it works* is a hard sentence to say. We are trying to make things that not only works, but works in the best possible way

Comment: @ElNicho, before saying that please add a group by to your reply so that "it also works". I don't know what makes you think subqueries are always inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
SELECT tableA.shipment, tableB.source, MAX(tableA.EnteredDate) AS "Last entered date"
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableB.shipment = tableA.shipment
```

Comment: Would max work even if I have multiple shipments?

Comment: Yes, it works! You can try yourself

Comment: You're welcome! You can edit this query to get ```MIN(tableA.EnteredDate)``` as well!

Comment: It wouldn't work without a group by really. Please add Group By.